# Flutter : SliverAppBar in LayoutBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

I want measure height of **SliverAppBar** using **Layout Builder**, Then after i get height of **SliverAppBar** height, i make condition with this height using ScrollController.

I have some code like this :

```
CustomScrollView(
          controller: _scrollController,
          slivers: <Widget>[
            LayoutBuilder(
              builder: (context, constraint) {
                message = constraint.biggest.height.toString();
                return SliverAppBar(
                  floating: false,
                  pinned: true,
                  expandedHeight: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setHeight(250),
                  leading: Container(
                    color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(.5),
                    child: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                      onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                    ),
                  ),
                  flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                    // titlePadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    title: Container(
                      width: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setWidth(250),
                      child: Text(
                        message ?? "Null",
                        style: ResponsiveUI.textNamaWartawanStylWhite,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      ),
                    ),
                    background: Container(
                      child: CachedNetworkImage(
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        imageUrl:
                            "${Urls.BASE_API_IMAGE}/wartawan/${widget.gambarWartawan}",
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(.5),
                      child: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.more_horiz),
                        onPressed: () => "",
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

But i get this error :

```
The following assertion was thrown building Listener:
A RenderViewport expected a child of type RenderSliver but received a child of type _RenderLayoutBuilder.

RenderObjects expect specific types of children because they coordinate with their children during layout and paint. For example, a RenderSliver cannot be the child of a RenderBox because a RenderSliver does not understand the RenderBox layout protocol.
The RenderViewport that expected a RenderSliver child was created by: Viewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#4f27a] ← Semantics ← _PointerListener ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#ed3fa] ← _PointerListener ← Listener ← _ScrollableScope ← _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#c7130] ← RepaintBoundary ← ⋯
The _RenderLayoutBuilder that did not match the expected child type was created by: LayoutBuilder ← Viewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#4f27a] ← Semantics ← _PointerListener ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#ed3fa] ← _PointerListener ← Listener ← _ScrollableScope ← _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#c7130] ← ⋯
User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was
    CustomScrollView 
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      ContainerRenderObjectMixin.debugValidateChild.<anonymous closure> 
#1      ContainerRenderObjectMixin.debugValidateChild
```

Can you help me with my case ? 
Thank you.

Comment: For future reference, typically errors should be written out as text, not given in screenshots.

Comment: @AdrianMurray Thank's, i have edited.

Comment: I've answered why you're getting the error, however, what's the point of the layoutbuilder? Why do you need to know the constraints? Also, constraints.maxHeight is the same as constraints.biggest.height but with a little less code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't place a non-sliver in a CustomScrollView. You may want to instead place the layoutbuilder inside of the FlexibleSpace's background.

Comment: Thank's for your response, but i have another problem, how i get value inside layout builder to outside layout builder ?  I have value from `message2 = constraint.biggest.height.toString();`, I want **message2** pass to outside layoutbuilder , but if i scrolled value outside layout builder not updating.

Comment: If the user scrolled <= 56 (it's minimum height FlexibleSpaceBar) Leading and Action Icon change color black.  else change color white. If you see my leading and action Icon outside the LayoutBuilder , i can't get the value inside the Layout builder . https://giphy.com/gifs/SUcJbIVCxYKQjVQtCL

Answer (score 4):

Try `SliverLayoutBuilder` widget.

**Explanation:**

You cannot place non-sliver widgets, such as `LayoutBuilder`, inside widgets that expects slivers as children, such as `CustomScrollView`.

For example, when you want to add padding to a sliver, you should use `SliverPadding` widget, instead of the normal `Padding` widget. Similarly, there's a sliver-version of `LayoutBuilder`, called `SliverLayoutBuilder`.